# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for Splash Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am getting error `Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` for Splash `Activity`. It is not showing error in all devices that's why I am not able to check it.
I am using `ActionBarSherLock` in my Project.
I have also checked Manifest. Splash activity is added there.

**Logcat from Play Store :**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{test.mytestbuddy.IIM_CAT/test.mytestbuddy.IIM_CAT.Splash}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.mytestbuddy.IIM_CAT.Splash
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2108)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.mytestbuddy.IIM_CAT.Splash
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2099)
```

Check snapshot of Properties -> Android and Java Build Path, if anything is wrong. But I got this error first time only from new version of android app.
I have assigned android-support-v4 file to ActionBarSherLock from another Project which is not current Project. And current Project contains its own android-support-v4.jar file.

**Manifest :**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test.mytestbuddy.IIM_CAT"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="1.30" >

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" >
    </uses-feature>

    <permission
        android:name="test.mytestbuddy.IIM_CAT.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="test.mytestbuddy.IIM_CAT.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MTBOfflineAppTheme" >
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="test.mytestbuddy.IIM_CAT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="test.mytestbuddy.IIM_CAT.GCMIntentService" />

        <activity
            android:name="test.mytestbuddy.IIM_CAT.Splash"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It may sound obvious, but... do you have a file called `/src/Splash.java` in your `test.mytestbuddy.IIM_CAT` project? Could you also show your Manifest?

Comment: It's not your **complete** manifest. Please post it complete

Comment: @FrankN.Stein, check nw...

Comment: You miss a declaration for a **main** activity in your manifest (set its category as **DEFAULT**). The one which is called in your Splash screen activity.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein, I have already added `DEFAULT` activities there.

Comment: I don't see a **DEFAULT** Activity, only the **LAUNCHER** one.

Answer (score 0):

change your manifest file like this.

add activity tag at first then after register receiver.

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="test.mytestbuddy.IIM_CAT"
android:versionCode="7"
android:versionName="1.30" >

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" >
</uses-feature>

<permission
    android:name="test.mytestbuddy.IIM_CAT.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="test.mytestbuddy.IIM_CAT.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MTBOfflineAppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="test.mytestbuddy.IIM_CAT.Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="test.mytestbuddy.IIM_CAT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="test.mytestbuddy.IIM_CAT.GCMIntentService" />
```

Comment: this can be the issue ??? because im using this from first version but got issue this time only.